# Gulp doesn't create folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

When I minified my css, I was left with an incorrect path to the fonts from various libraries. So, I created a task to move the fonts from my `bower_components/` folder to `dist/public/fonts`:

```
gulp.task('doit', function() {
    gulp.src(["public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/*", "public/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/public/fonts"));
});
```

Basically that should throw any fonts I need into a generic fonts folder, which my minified css should now be able to access.

But after I run it, `dist/public/fonts` doesn't exist. Why not?

Comment: `/public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/*` -- why is this an absolute path. This must be a relative path and it may not start with forward slash.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar Sorry, that was a typo when I was writing this post! I've edited it.

Comment: Where are you running this? And am I right in assuming that from that directory, you have a `public` dir, and a `dist/public` dir?

Comment: @rublex So...did we get you fixed up?

Comment: Doubt it, I'm trying to do the same thing. I'm guessing he found a solution in the end and didn't revisit, so for closure, by the description he gave, he wants gulp to automagically create the folder structure dist/public/fonts if it doesnt exist. And you assumed incorrectly :)

Comment: I had a same issue and prefixing destination path with `./` fixed it: i.e. `.pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/public/fonts"));`. when i specify only `dist/public/fonts`, it doesn't automatically create the directory.

Answer (score 5):

I don't fully understand the paths you're `src`-ing (`public/bower_components`?), but I believe you'll want to use the [`base` option for `gulp.src`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase).

Because these two globs will have different bases, I'd suggest breaking it into two separate tasks, and building a third to aggregate them into a single. Otherwise you'll need to get into merging streams or the `addSrc` plugin.

```
gulp.task('copy:fonts:bootstrap', function () {
    return gulp.src(
        [
            'public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**/*'
        ],
        {
            base: 'public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts'
        }
    )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/public/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('copy:fonts:fontawesome', function () {
    return gulp.src(
        [
            'public/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**/*'
        ],
        {
            base: 'public/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts'
        }
    )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/public/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('copy:fonts', ['copy:fonts:bootstrap', 'copy:fonts:fontawesome']);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](http://www.levihackwith.com/how-to-make-gulp-copy-a-directory-and-its-contents/), specify your src like this:

```
gulp.src(['src/js/**/*.js'], { base: 'src' })
  .pipe(foo())
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./public/"));
```

and it will auto create the destination directories for you. In this case, the 'js' folder will be created in public if it doesnt exist already.

Comment: The link to the article, you have referred to, is broken. Could you please update it?

Comment: I pasted that answer 4 years ago. I'm sure there many more articles out with more updated solutions