# gulp doesn't create any directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, frontend

My workspace is directory "Super gulp" and below, there is directories about my files. The problem is that I was converting my .pug files into html files, and put them in directory "goal" but when I run "dev" nothing comes out. I've tried method:([Gulp doesn't create folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360885/gulp-doesnt-create-folder)) and found the result didn't changed.

[image: file directory]

[image: source code]

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example to convert pug files into html files and put watcher on them.

***Step: 1*** ->
First install npm packages for compiling pug and watch for changes

`npm i -S gulp-pug gulp-watch`

***Step: 2*** -> 
Then create and config your gulpfile.js.

First import an npm modules

*gulpfile.js*

```
const pug = require('gulp-pug');
const watch = require('gulp-watch');

//Then create compiling task

gulp.task('pug',() => {
 return gulp.src('./src/*.pug')
 .pipe(pug({
    doctype: 'html',
    pretty: false
 }))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/goal/'));
});

//And then create watcher

gulp.task('watch',() => {
 return watch('./src/*.pug', { ignoreInitial: false })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('pug'));
 });
```

***Step: 3*** -> Run the below cmd to run the task

```
gulp watch
```

Comment: @JustinSeo:  If the annswer worked and helpful for you. Please don't forget to accept and upvote it.